# How to use NextJS's 'useRouter()' hook inside Storybook

Tags: next.js, storybook

I've been attempting to use the useRouter hooks from Next.js inside Storybook. However, every time I load up Storybook, I get 'cannot read property 'pathname' of null'. How might I resolve this issue?

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const NavStrip = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    ...
            <Link href="/dashboard" passHref>
              <StyledLink active={router.pathname === "/dashboard"}>
                ...
              </StyledLink>
            </Link>
    ...
         )
}
```

NavStrip.stories.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import NavStrip from "./index";

export default {
  component: NavStrip,
  title: "NavStrip",
};

export const Default = () => <NavStrip />;
```

Answer (score 14):

You should use [Storybook Addon Next Router](https://github.com/lifeiscontent/storybook-addon-next-router#readme). As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62158996/13495096) states, you need to run `Link` inside Next and Storybook doesn't load Next, so this addon will mock the `Router` for you.

In my config, all I needed to do was:

```
// .storybook/preview.js
import { withNextRouter } from 'storybook-addon-next-router';

export const decorators = [withNextRouter()]
```

That should fix it.

Comment: It fixed the Storybook preview error, but after compiling I still get `TypeError: router$1 is null`, so useRouter() returns null

Answer (score 3):

The setup for [storybook-addon-next-router](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-next-router) has changed a bit.

For version 3.x:

Add the addon to your configuration in `.storybook/main.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...config,
  addons: [
    ...your addons
    "storybook-addon-next-router",
  ],
};
```

Add the RouterContext.Provider to `.storybook/preview.js`:

```js
import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router-context"; // next 12
// import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router-context"; // next 11.1
// import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/next-server/lib/router-context"; // next < 11.1

export const parameters = {
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
  },
}
```

There are some other options (e.g. the ability to customize what the Next router provides). See [the documentation](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-next-router).

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to use the `storybook-addon-next-router` package mentioned in the previous answer. You can now integrate Next.js and use Next router automatically. See the [docs here](https://storybook.js.org/blog/integrate-nextjs-and-storybook-automatically/).

```js
export const Example = {
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      router: {
        basePath: '/profile',
        query: {
           slug: "example-slug"
        }
      },
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: In Storybook >7 this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Storybook components run outside of the Next environment and outside of the `page` component which enables the use of `next/router`. Therefore you will not be able to use this outside of your Next page and its children.

Next's router functionalities are created in a Context API [provider](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/7f6c6f031611057d44b253fbd53473471a84504f/packages/next/client/index.js#L486), therefore in order to use [`useRouter`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/7f6c6f031611057d44b253fbd53473471a84504f/packages/next/client/router.ts#L124) your component must be a child of that provider (which in the case of storybook it will never be).

Comment: I know this post is pretty old but how are we supposed to simulate it then ?

Answer (score 0):

Since v7, Storybook has its own [Next.js support package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs) which is easily configurable.

Simply add it to your project:

```
npm i -D @storybook/nextjs
```

And update Storybooks `main.js` by adding:

```
framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find why it doesn't work with Next.js 13.6.x and Storybook 7.x ...

Although everyone says you just need to use the package `@storybook/nextjs` and provide the `nextjs: { router: {} }` to the `parameters` of the Story that you need to be mocked with App Router.

For me, the essential thing that worked was to **also add `appDirectory: true`**. For example:

```
export const HomeStory: Story = {
  // your other story parameters are here
  // ...  
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      appDirectory: true,
      router: {
        basePath: '/',
      },
    }
  }
};
```