# Storybook Navbar component breaks through useRouter()

Tags: next.js, storybook

I have a Navbar with a Navigation Links, which are highlighted as active, depending on the page a user is on.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router'


const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', url: '/', active: true},
  { name: 'Quiz', url:'/quiz', active: false}
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}


export const Navigation = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <div className="flex space-x-4 justify-self-center">
            {navigation.map((item) => (
            <a
                key={item.name}
                href={item.url}
                className={`px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium ${
                router.asPath === item.url ? "bg-gray-900 text-white" : 'text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700'
                }`}
                aria-current={item.active? 'page' : undefined}
            >
                {item.name}
            </a>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

It works as is should, but I can't create a story for it, because of the Next Router. I get the following error: Cannot read property 'asPath' of null.

I tried to follow the instructions in the answer I found here: [How to use NextJS's 'useRouter()' hook inside Storybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138429/how-to-use-nextjss-userouter-hook-inside-storybook) , but unfortunately it didn't give me the result I am striving for. So basically my "Story-Navbar" shouldn't redirect, but just highlight the Navigation Link, while I click on it. Is that possible? Here is the story for Navigation:

```
import { Navigation } from './Navigation';

export default {
    title: 'Example/Navigation',
    component: Navigation,
  };


export const DefautlNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navigation />
  )
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into a similar issue where useRouter() returns null in my unit tests

Comment: I did! I am not sure, but I guess on top aff all the instructions I installed some kind of missing npm package, I am not sure, if it was tslib ... Here is the full repo on github, maybe it helps ... https://github.com/katharinasch/nextjs-apollo-starter-app

Comment: I'll check it out, thx!

Answer (score 1):

The storybook Next.js router [add-on](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@gogaille/storybook-addon-next-router/) works for `useRouter()` hook. Here is the example in their docs:

```
import { withNextRouter } from 'storybook-addon-next-router';
import MyComponentThatHasANextLink from '../component-that-has-a-next-link';

export default {
  title: 'My Story',
  decorators: [withNextRouter], // not necessary if defined in preview.js
};

// if you have the actions addon
// you can click the links and see the route change events there
export const Example = () => <MyComponentThatHasANextLink />;

Example.story = {
  parameters: {
    nextRouter: {
      path: '/profile/[id]',
      asPath: '/profile/lifeiscontent',
      query: {
        id: 'lifeiscontent',
      },
    },
  },
};
```